# Gradle Android Studio App writing the procfile for Heroku

Tags: java, android, gradle, heroku, procfile

I'm trying to deploy the app to heroku, but in order to do that I need to declare a process type through the procfile in heroku.

I researched the procfile but have no idea how to get the right command for my java gradle android studio app as I'm not using ratpack or springboot, so I'm wondering what the command is.

I know that the process type needs to be: "web: " but i don't know what to write after that.

Comment: What command do you run locally to start the process? Generally that should follow the `web` entry in your `Procfile`

Comment: ./gradlew stage do I just write that in the web: ?

Comment: gradlew stage doesn't run an app. it compiles it.